# Auto text bouncing back and fourth CSS like marquee for long text label

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have a requirement to show auto movable text feature (just like marquee with alternative behavior) on the label which has long text.

[image]

As you can see **Created On: 28 Nov, 2017** label in sap.m.ObjectAttribute is just got wrapped because of the default behavior of ObjectListItem control. I am looking for the **CSS** that could make the wrapped text movable front and back just like marquee with alternative behavior, so that i can see entire unwrapped text bouncing front and back.

Please refer to [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POBMOL), In this when you mouse-over the div, the label starts scrolling left and when you take away the mouse from the div, it will scroll back to its initial point.

I am looking for the CSS like this but with the auto effect. So that once i have applied to any possible label which have long text, the label should auto start the scroll back and front automatically.

Kindly help me on this.

Another example based on [marquee](https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.blue-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 40%;
}

.blue-btn a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  /* important */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.blue-btn,
.first-link {
  -moz-transition: 3.3s;
  transition: 3.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.blue-btn {
  height: 64px;
  font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.blue-btn:hover {
  background-color: #003D99;
}

.blue-btn a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first-link {
  margin-left: 0em;
}

.blue-btn:hover .first-link {
  margin-left: -300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-btn">
  <a class="first-link" href="">Thisisanextreamlylongtext,kindoflikeanamecouldbe</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should use javascript for that - have u try that way ?

Comment: Yes, I need some javascript/CSS. I only have the snippet example as a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use infinite animation to automatically scroll `.link`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
.link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 2;
}
.link_animated {
  animation: backAndForth 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes backAndForth {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  10% { transform: translateX(0); }
  45% { transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 200px)); }
  55% { transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 200px)); }
  90% { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="link link_animated" href="">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </a>
</div>
```